# R: Least squares estimation in linear equation systems

Tags: r, estimation, standard-error, linear-equation

I'm going to estimate some parameters of linear equation systems with repeated measures. My equations will look like this:

Variant1: [image: X_i + K_j + X_ij = K_ij]

Variant2: [image: X_i + K_j + x_ij * X_i * K_j = K_ij]

At least 10 values (repeated measures; technical replicates) are known for every [image: K_j] and [image: K_ij]. I want to estimate the values for [image: X_i] and [image: X_ij] resp. [image: x_ij].

Additionally I'd like to know the standard error of these estimates, if possible.

In R, my data set would look like this (in reality I have :

```
i <- rep(1:3, each = 30)
j <- rep(rep(1:3, each = 10), 3)

K.i  <- rep(c(6, 5, 10), each = 30) + rnorm(90)
K.ij <- K.i + rnorm(90)

# X_i, X_ij and x_ij should be 0 (since I assumed K_j being K_ij + normal noise

data <- cbind(i, j, K.i, K.ij)
```

How can I estimate the expected parameter values (minimizing the sums of squares) and the standard errors of these estimates in R?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: In the second variant, should the second $X_i$ be a $K_i$?

Comment: @jochen: No, it should remain the $X_i$. The last term is added to represent the interaction between both variables, the known $K_j$ as well as the unknown $X_i$. Hope it makes sense. Please let me know if not ;)